# ошибка String format

Tags: java, android, строки, adapter, format

Написал свой SimpleCursorAdapter, вот его метод:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    String hours = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("HOURS"));
    String minutes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MINUTES"));
    String days = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DAYS"));
    TextView hourTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hours);
    TextView minutesTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    TextView daysTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.days);
    if(Integer.parseInt(hours) >= 0 || Integer.parseInt(hours) <= 9){
        hourTV.setText(String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(hours)));
    }
    else {
        hourTV.setText(hours);
    }
    if(Integer.parseInt(minutes) >= 0 || Integer.parseInt(minutes) <= 9){
        minutesTV.setText(String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(minutes)));
    }
    else {
        minutesTV.setText(minutes);
    }
    daysTV.setText(days);
}
```

Вроде делал всё по инструкции, но мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier: 02d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в записи в SQLite. Вопрос более неактуален

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть

```
hourTV.setText(String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(hours)));
```

`%d` ожидает увидеть целое число в качестве аргумента, а у вас строка.

Comment: исправил, всё равно эта же ошибка